# The bike derailer will automatically drop to the lowest gear in the rear whenever my cadence slows

Tags: derailleur

I have a [REI Coop CTY 2.2 bicycle](https://www.rei.com/product/121599/co-op-cycles-cty-22-bike).  Whenever I am biking and my cadence slows down, the bicycle derailer automatically (I am not shifting) to the lowest gear on the rear derailer.  Any suggestions on how to fix other than not to get tired?  The derailer has been replaced, the chain has been replaced and the bicycle has been tuned by a good bike mechanic.  Thanks

Comment: could you clarify "lowest gear?"  That can be interpreted two different ways.  Is it the smallest cog (fewest number of teeth), or is it the largest cog (largest diameter/most teeth)?  The smallest cog is also referred as the highest gear on a bike.

Comment: If it the harder rear cog, its going down the cassette under gravity and spring-tension?   That implies the shifter is not holding tension on the inner cable?   Why Cadence is involved, that's weird.

Comment: Years ago there were automatic mechanical derailleurs, more recently there are electronic ones. ones that did this, has the bike been fitted with one of these?

Comment: Did you buy it new?  It comes from the factory with normal Shimano Alivio derailleurs, but a previous owner (if any) could have changed things.  Any wobble in the back wheel? Or in the cassette as you spin the wheel (forwards? Backwards?).  Does it shift all the way down if you start in a really small sprocket, or just shift a couple of gears?

Comment: For reference, the current version has an Acera triple front, 9s rear (11-36) cassette, and Alivio FD, RD, and shifters.